# Why I get downvoted in questions that are removed

Tags: discussion

Recently I am getting downvoted for questions that, if I remember well, I've only reviewed and that now are removed. Since they are removed, I can not do anything to improve whatever I did wrong.

Here are some of them:

[image]

How could I solve this?

Comment: You're misunderstanding the data; you're not "getting downvoted" on deleted questions, you're losing the rep you gained from the question _because_ the question was deleted...

Comment: Ahh, Sorry, I misunderstood indeed, thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

These are not "downvotes".

Those are questions that you've [suggested an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4905991) to. Since the edit was approved, you earned +2 reputation points for your effort.

Those questions have since been [deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23869462/when-i-use-android-pinyin-inputmethod-throw-java-lang-nullpointerexception), taking all associated reputation to the grave along with them. That would include reputation the asker earned from votes on the question, reputation anyone had earned from answers, and reputation you earned from suggesting edits.

There's nothing really to be concerned about. You aren't *punished* for this, you just don't get to keep reputation for content that no longer exists on the site.

But if you're really worried about it, avoid editing crap. It is the stuff most likely to get deleted. :-)

Comment: Thank you, I now understand, Your answer will be accepted in 5 minutes ;-)

Comment: "Polishing a turd" is the colloquial expression.